# How to exit the workflow of github actions?

Tags: github, yaml, logic, github-actions, cicd

I wrote an yaml script in github actions in which there was a logic by which if the upload file size that is greater than 15mb in github using push or pull request to the main branch then the workflow should exit by throwing exit status 1 and checks should get fail. But my problem is that the workflow is not exiting, they are passing checks, even my file is greater than 15 mb. this is the yaml file

```
name: File Size Limit Check
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  check_file_size:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Check file size
        run: |
          MAX_FILE_SIZE=15000000
          # Get the list of modified files in the commit or pull request
          git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }} | while read file; do
            file_size=$(wc -c < "$file")
            if [ $file_size -gt $MAX_FILE_SIZE ]; then
              echo "File '$file' exceeds the maximum allowed size of $MAX_FILE_SIZE bytes."
              exit 1
            fi
          done
```

I couldn't figure out that why even after getting exit code 1 the checks are getting pass. I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The part after `|` is in a subshell, and you're exiting from just that subshell. This is a minimal reproducer:

```bash
echo blah | while read line; do exit 1; done
```

You'll notice that this doesn't exit. If it's written like this instead, it exits:

```bash
while read line; do exit 1; done < <(echo blah)
```

In your case:

```bash
while read file; do
    file_size=$(wc -c < "$file")
    if [ "$file_size" -gt "$MAX_FILE_SIZE" ]; then
        echo "File '$file' exceeds the maximum allowed size of $MAX_FILE_SIZE bytes."
        exit 1
    fi
done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }})
```